# Setting variables as workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set a variable to always refer to a specific workbook; right now I am doing it the way listed below but I don´t want it to open the document each time.  What should I have instead? Also please note if any of the variables need to change or something along those lines.

```
Dim wbkC as workbook

Set WbkC = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\Reporting\ReportCompare.xls")
```

Comment: What are you using this for? You could hide the workbook or only use the address if tor a formula?

Comment: Use `wbck.windows(1).visable = false`

Comment: @glh I´m basically using it to make it easier to refer to ranges.  Instead of typing out workbooks(name).worksheets("sheet1").range("A").value  I would prefer to type wbkA.worksheets("sheet1").range("A").value

Comment: Only open workbook files are part of the `Workbooks` collection, so you could use the `Path` (as String) in @glh's first comment, or you could open the file and hide it per his second suggestion.

Comment: Probably you need to open the file and hide it, in order to accomplish your specific task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom function to open it if it's not, or grab the open copy if it is.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim wbkC As Workbook

    'This will open it
    Set wbkC = GetWorkbookReference("G:\Reporting\ReportCompare.xls")

    'This will not open it b/c it's already open
    Set wbkC = GetWorkbookReference("G:\Reporting\ReportCompare.xls")

End Sub
Public Function GetWorkbookReference(ByVal sFullName As String) As Workbook

    Dim wbReturn As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
        'If it's open, get a reference to it
        Set wbReturn = Workbooks(Dir$(sFullName))
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If it's not open, open it
    If wbReturn Is Nothing Then
        Set wbReturn = Workbooks.Open(sFullName)
    End If

    Set GetWorkbookReference = wbReturn

End Function
```